# ASP.NET local SQL Server database C# gridview data binding Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, gridview, local-database

I need some help because I've been trying different things but nothing seems to work properly the question itself is the one below.

How can I bind data to a grid-view in Visual Studio 2013 with a local SQL Server database using the code behind C# ?

Here is the C# I'm trying:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Guillermo\Desktop\HorsensHospital\App_Data\HospitalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Task_temp_name], [Task_templatesID] FROM [Task_templates]", con);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors

Answer (score 1):

You just assing your empty `DataSet` to your Gridview's `DataSource`.

You need to use [`.Fill` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) fo fill your `DataSet` of `SqlDataAdapter`. You don't need to use `ExecuteNonQuery`. This method just executes your query. It doesn't return any data or something as a result.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`. You don't need to `.Close()` your database connections and objects when you use it.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Task_temp_name], [Task_templatesID] FROM [Task_templates]";
    using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         sda.Fill(ds);
         GridView1.DataSource = ds;
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `Fill` method to fill your your dataset that is why i think you are not able to display `gridview`.

Fill Method is very Improtant method Bcoz whatever your query is returning that should be filled into your dataset & then that dataset is binded by your `Gridiview`
Hope this will help you

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Guillermo\Desktop\HorsensHospital\App_Data\HospitalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Task_temp_name], [Task_templatesID] FROM [Task_templates]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

}

**Note** : You need to create your connection string in Web.Config. Bcoz If you have created your connection string there then you will not need to create that again. Once creating there you will just need to call that from the `Web.config`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString);
```

This is the syntax for calling connection string from web.config

Answer (score 0):

You should use statement like this :
when you use SqlDataAdapter you should fill an dataset with Fill Method 
then set the DataSource Properties Of GridView

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Task_temp_name], [Task_templatesID] FROM     [Task_templates]", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```