# mysql_fetch_array in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, php, sql, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to read data from database then put this into a table. rows in the table are created automatically depending on how many rows there are in database. I have done this in php using mysql_fetch_array but cannot seem to do it in asp.net webforms. My idea is to use this query to get the information and store in the labels in the server page and create a table there with coloumns data filled using the labels.  Here is my code in the 'page_load' Thank you:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Surgery</th>
            <th>PatientID</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>



           string query= "select surgery,patientID, location from details";
            SqlCommand result= new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            result.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader getInfo= result.ExecuteReader())


                while (getInfo.Read())
                {
                    Label1.Text = getInfo["surgery"].ToString();
                    Label2.Text = getInfo["patientID"].ToString();
                    Label3.Text = getInfo["location"].ToString();


                }
```

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select surgery, PatientID, location from details", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                conn.Close();

Comment: Use `GridView`. Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET local SQL Server database C# gridview data binding Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817272/asp-net-local-sql-server-database-c-sharp-gridview-data-binding-visual-studio-20)

Comment: Already tried that does not seem to work??

Comment: The requirements can be fulfilled by GridView easily, did you try that? If yes then please share that code.

Comment: I am missing a directive or assembly reference for 'dataset'  ???

Comment: Add reference for `System.Data` in your project.

Comment: still errors on GridView1?

Comment: Please add your code in your question, both c# and asp.

Comment: this is my code. Is this meant to create a table automatically?   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select surgery, PatientID, location from details", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                conn.Close();

Comment: The code is fine, now what is the error?

Comment: gridview has a directive or reference erorr?

Comment: Sorry it says GridView1 does not exist in current context? Is it some sort of variable name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `GridView` in your `aspx` code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surgery" DataField="surgery" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PatientID" DataField="patientID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Location" DataField="location" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You C# code is fine, just close the connection before binding to gridview:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select surgery, PatientID, location from details", conn);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
sda.Fill(dt);

conn.Close();

GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you :) appreciate the help. to style it would be same as normal tables? am i correct?

Comment: yeah, just write a css class and set its property `cssClass="youCSSclass"`

Comment: thankyou. Last question say I would like to add a delete button next to each row. How would I pass the 'id' through the server? I have done this in php and would use the same approach. Add extra colunm and change the DataField in aspx to the 'button_click' and place the code in that functiion in C#? Do I use %button_click% if I would like to use the variable in the aspx page. Thank you

Comment: Actually its a bit complex to implement CRUD using GridView than in php. I share an article with you please do not go for just copy paste, read it and understand how it works. Here is it: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-Delete-using-Single-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Hi thank you for that info. Is there no simpler method for the edit and delete?

Comment: Honestly, it is the simplest one :) You'll realize when you'll use it 2,3 times.